# Generating APA Text Tables in RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I'm trying to generate this text table for a research proposal. I'm writing in RMarkdown and using the papaja plugin to get APA6 styling and to generate the PDF using this command:

```
rmarkdown::render("appendix.Rmd")
```

This table will be included in landscape mode. (I used MS Word to create this version.) I'm open to whatever packages or methods would work.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a minimal document and the text for the table as text in addition to the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using latex. I noticed there was a package available for converting it to landscape mode, but decided to format it in portrait instead.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Decision factors and operationalizations.}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{p{.18\linewidth}p{.1\linewidth}p{.72\linewidth}}
\hline
 & Level & Operationalization \\ \hline
Expected return & High & The startup is expected to return 10x. \\
 & Low & The startup is expected to return 5x. \\
Expected time horizon & High & A liquidity event is expected in 5-10 years. 
\\
 & Low & A liquidity event is expected in 2-3 years. \\
Coinvestment & High & The investment will be made with other well-regarded 
investors. \\
 & Low & The investment will be made alone. \\
Participation & High & The investment will be an active investment with 
direct interaction with the founder. \\
 & Low & The investment will be a passive investment with no interaction with 
the founder. \\
Social impact & High & The startup is building a product that could have a 
significant positive impact on society. \\
 & Low & The startup is building an interesting product. \\
Investment size & High & The minimum investment required to participate is 
large. \\
 & Low & The minimum investment required to participate is small. \\
Entrepreneurial personality & High & The founder is charismatic, self- 
confident, hard-working, but appears set in their plans and maintains a 
cordial demeanor. \\
 & Low & The founder does not exhibit any particular personality traits that 
stand out, positively or negatively. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the contents of the table in a `data.frame`, `papaja`'s `apa_table()` can generate landscape LaTeX tables:

```
df <- cars[1:5, ]

colnames(df) <- paste0("\emph{", colnames(df) "}")

apa_table(
  df
  , caption = "This is a caption"
  , landscape = TRUE
)
```